# Как получить нужные мне данные из json

Tags: php, ajax, json

Здравствуйте. На странице **1** Средствами ajax отправляю GET запрос на страницу **2** и получаю в ответ такую строку:

```
{"status":"ok","code":0,"data":{"id":"7777777777777777","agTrnId":null,"coId":"dfgdsfgsdgdfg","coPurseId":"402802693551","paymentNo":"6891843","paywayId":"sdvdfvdfbdfgdfgdf","chargebacked":null,"state":"7","result":"0","expired":"2017-10-13 15:59:06","processed":"2017-09-13 15:59:06","created":"2017-09-13 15:59:06","coAmount":"5000.00","coRefund":"5000.0000","ikFee":"150.0000","ikFeeIn":"0.0000","ikFeeOut":"150.0000","ikPsFeeIn":"0.0000","agFeeRate":"0.00","agReward":"0.0000","ikPrice":"5150.0000","psAmount":"5150.0000","psIkFee":"0.0000","psExchFee":"0.0000","psFeeIn":"0.0000","psFeeOut":"0.0000","psPrice":"5150.00","psAccepted":null,"ikExchRate":"1","ikExchRateSys":null,"psCurRate":"1","stateName":"success","currencyId":40,"currencyCodeChar":"RUB","currencyCodeNum":"643"}}
```

Сам ajax запрос:

```
   $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/curl.php',
        data: {
          ik_inv_id: idIK
        }
      }).then(function(resp_json) {
        alert(resp_json);
    });
```

Вопрос. Каким образом на странице **1** и на странице **2** вывести значение нужного мне параметра, а именно **coAmount** ?

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

UPD. Полученное значение нужно записать в переменную php - $coSum;

Comment: что-то непонятно. ajax подразумевает, что вы отправляете запрос и страница не обновляется

Comment: @JurijJazdanov тогда как мне поступить лучше? мне нужно отправить GET запрос, и в ответе я получаю json строку с которой нужно взять значения для работы с ними в php...

Comment: для работы в php с json используётсе json_decode()/json_encode().  В js JSON.parse(). И если уж хотите отправлять ajax'ом json лучше используйте POST